# closing a popup when opening another popup

Tags: c#, javascript, wysihtml5

I have icons in my rich text area - icons for: link, insert image, insert column. On each button when clicked it opens a popup which the user completes the task. Each button functions like this went clicked:

```
onclick="$.Forms.WysiHtml5.InitEditor($(this));"
```

and when the click on the icon again it disappears:

```
onclick="$.Forms.WysiHtml5.ClosePopover($(this));"
```

**Problem:**
When i click a button and popup shows then i go click another button - another popup comes up leaving the page with two popups showing. I want it so that when i click on a button if there is a popup it will close and new popup for the clicked button will show.

Based on suggested answer below:

```
'<a class="btn popover_btn" href="javascript:;" title="' + locale.css.columns.insert + '"'
                                    + 'data-placement="top" data-popover-selector="#RichText_ColsPopover"'
                                    + '$(#DynamicEditorForm)on("click", ".tool", function(){add close and open stuff}); tabindex="-1"><i class="icon-th"></i></a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a event delegation to the container:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".tool", function(){
    // Close all
    // Open new one
})
```

Comment: so i have what i am trying to implement based on what you shared  - if you can take a look and confirm that it is possible to do.